# inscription form SQL Symfony2

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I'm currently working on a school board. I got several activities, and any registered student can join them. So far, I got a user database, and ever user got a "Activities" column, summing up every activity they signed for. I also got a table with every activity created so far.

My goal is to create a simple input, a button, to allow them to join the activity.

I created the form, but I just can't figure out how to specify the appropriate sql request and turn it into a simple button.

I suppose it would look like

```
$action = mysql_query(insert into activities joined_by=$user this_activity);
```

And the form would be like

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Inscription" action="$action"/>
</form>
```

To make a long story short, is there any simple way to send an SQL request using an input submit button ?

Thank You

Comment: sorry but it looks like you have no idea what you are doing. First of all, "action" should be places in form, not input. Also if you have an idea of how does symfony (or mvc in general) works, your action should lead to url where your controller will take care of inserting data to db based on user/activity

Comment: Thank you ! I solved my problem, idd, it was because I put the "action" inside of the input (I admit I'm not very familiar with forms...)